# Improve internet at an apartment

Tags: internet, speed, connection, ethernet

My situation is that I am a college student living in an apartment complex using AT&T internet (included).  Since everyone in the complex is on the same line, even if I am connected to the ethernet directly from the wall, the internet either doesn't work half of the time or it is VERY slow.  As a student alone this is a big issue for studying, but I also run a web business which makes this an even bigger issue.

I tried contacting AT&T to see if I could get my own dedicated line, but the apartment complex apparently won't allow it for some reason.  Does anyone know of anything I could try to help improve the situation without paying $60+/mo to get wireless 3G (which would be ridiculous to have to use at my desk).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what you're doing, you might get an advantage using ssh tunneling.  I've found that once a ssh connection is established over slow or unreliable channels, response times and data rates are higher--it seems the routers keep some sort of persistent information available until the tunnel closes.  I'm not a networking expert and I don't claim to understand this at the OSI networking level, but it has been my personal experience.

If you have an ISP like [Panix](http://www.panix.com), you can ssh tunnel to their host and then use their proxy server, etc.

Comment: The performance of this depends on the routers, etc. Not all allow the persistent connections to have a dedicated amount of throughput.

Comment: So how exactly would I go about setting this up?

Comment: Setting up the tunnel kind of depends on what you're doing.  For my ISP, some instructions are here:  http://www.panix.com/help/proxy.html

You might want to make "how can I use ssh tunneling for [my purpose]" a new question.  Don't forget to mention your ISP and your operating system.

Comment: Wow, so I just got this setup and my download speed according to speedtest.net went from <1M/s to >10M/s!

Answer (score 3):

Be honest, explain your situation to the landlord or whoever controls the internet at your location and ask them to give you higher priority in the router's [**QOS**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_of_service). After all, **you are paying for it** and you deserve your share.

Comment: +1 that's pretty much all you can do, short of illegal activities or biting the bullet and subscribing for mobile broadband.

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried this.  I'll keep trying if I have to.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your web business involves running some web services at your apartment complex, you may want to consider paying for some *cloud* hosting. There are a number of virtual private server hosting companies that do it for cheap ($7/mo or so).

Another thing that you can do to help reduce the bandwidth requirements for your home server is to employ some sort of *content delivery network* services to offload the bandwidth requirements.